# Как получить доступ к массиву, если он запакован в object

Tags: c#, массивы, типы-данных

На входе метода я получаю тип object внутри которого имею массив. Вопрос, как мне подступиться к элементам массива. Object[0] не получается, хотя я вижу что там массив и элементы с индексами.

Вот код метода, который возвращает object.

```
 public object GetImportedFromSQLite(string connstring, string idrecord,string tablename,string Idname)
        {
            object imported = null;
            using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(connstring))
            {
                connect.Open();
                using (SQLiteCommand fmd = connect.CreateCommand())
                {
                    var sb= new StringBuilder();
                    var que = sb.Append("SELECT * FROM "+tablename+" where "+Idname+"="+idrecord);


                    fmd.CommandText = que.ToString();
                    fmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SQLiteDataReader r = fmd.ExecuteReader();


                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        object[] values = new object[r.FieldCount];
                        r.GetValues(values);
                        imported= values;
                    }


                }
            }
            return imported;
        }
```

Вот так я хочу получить из него массив, а потом элементы массива.Но выходит ошибка.

```
var rezultFromSqLite=INSTANCE.GetImportedFromSQLite
string[]parametrsFromSqLite=(string[])rezultFromSqLite;
```

Получаю ошибку приведения.

Comment: Если придерживаться терминологии, то массивы не упаковываются

Comment: ты возвращаешь `object[]`, обернутый в `object` а развернуть пытаешься в `string[]`, естественно это не работает. Вместо этого надо было разворачивать в `object[]` и затем уже делать Cast или OfType

Comment: @Grundy да именно, спасибо

Comment: кстати, если у тебя всегда возвращается массив object, почему возвращаемый тип у функции просто object?

Comment: @Grundy Ошибка, увы недосмотрел

Comment: там еще обрати внимание, что ты возвращаешь только последнюю строку из набора, все остальные теряются

Comment: @Grundy Она строка всегда будет одна, потому как уникальна.

Comment: Тогда нет смысла делать `while(r.Read())` достаточно `if(r.Read())`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо подправлю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно [привести тип](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) к массиву:

```
//неявное приведение к объекту
object obj = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
//явное приведение к массиву
int[] arr = (int[]) obj;
```

Укажите нужный тип массива вместо `int`.

**Дополнение в комментарии:**

> Да с упаковкой и распаковкой я знаком и ваше решение правильное, но оно тривиальное. я думал так, вот у меня есть целый object внутри него массив, это поля от запроса к базе, я думал, что, так как это массив и значит в этой последовательности можно как то обратиться короче и сразу к нужному элементу, например в моем случае это 1 и второй элемент. нулевой элемент мне не нужен.

Не думаю, что есть хороший способ делать это без явного приведения. Если бы к элементам массива можно было обращаться через переменную типа `object`, то сам тип массива потерял бы смысл.

Приведение можно писать в одну строку:

```
int a = ((int[]) obj)[1];
```

но это некрасиво.

Впрочем, вижу два варианта для сокращения и улучшения кода.

1. Нормальное ООП: если метод принимает массив, объявите аргумент как массив.

Вместо

```
void Method(object obj)
```

Сделайте:

```
void Method(int[] arr)
```

и обращайтесь по индексам свободно. Если метод должен принимать иногда массив, а иногда другие объекты, то сделайте несколько перегрузок метода.

Так Вы получите проверку типа и безопасное обращение к массиву.

2. Использовать динамическую типизацию.

Если так напрягает статический тип, то используйте динамический. Объявите аргумент метода как `dynamic`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Method(new []{1, 2, 3});
}

private static void Method(dynamic obj) {
    Console.WriteLine(obj[1]);
}
```

C# поддерживает тип `dynamic` который может принимать любой тип и через который можно обращаться к элементам массива. При этом Вы потеряете проверку на соответствие типа, но т.к. сейчас у Вас там `object`, её у Вас и так нет.

**Дополнение по обновлению вопроса:**

```
var rezultFromSqLite=INSTANCE.GetImportedFromSQLite
string[]parametrsFromSqLite=(string[])rezultFromSqLite;
```

`rezultFromSqLite` переменная типа `object`, которая содержит массив типа `object[]`.

Массив объектов нельзя напрямую привести к массиву строк. Вот такое приведение сработает, например:

```
object[]parametrsFromSqLite=(object[])rezultFromSqLite;
```

Но, раз метод у Вас возвращает массив, то лучше и указать это в сигнатуре метода:

```
//возвращаем массив объектов
 public object[] GetImportedFromSQLite(string connstring, string idrecord,string tablename,string Idname)
{
     //object imported = null; обойдемся без 
     ...
     while (r.Read())
     {
          object[] values = new object[r.FieldCount];
          r.GetValues(values);
          return values;
     }
     ...
     return null;
}
```

После этого никакого приведения не требуется:

```
var rezultFromSqLite=INSTANCE.GetImportedFromSQLite
Console.WriteLine(rezultFromSqLite[0]);
```

И если нужен массив строк, а не объектов, то приведите массив объектов к массиву строк и возвращайте его:

```
//возвращаем массив строк
public string[] GetImportedFromSQLite(string connstring, string idrecord,string tablename,string Idname)
{
     ...
     while (r.Read())
     {
          object[] values = new object[r.FieldCount];
          r.GetValues(values);
          return values.Select(v => v?.ToString()).ToArray();
     }
     ...
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Да спасибо, но я думал как то хитрее можно. например через linq

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Для одного объекта это не нужно. А если этот объект вложен в какой-то другой или в коллекцию/массив, то расскажите об этом поподробнее. В Linq есть `Cast` и `OfType`, которые приводят тип для всей последовательности.

Comment: Да с упаковкой и распаковкой я знаком и ваше решение правильное, но оно тривиальное. я думал так, вот у меня есть целый object внутри него  массив, это поля от запроса к базе, я думал, что, так как это массив и значит в этой последовательности можно как то обратиться короче и сразу к нужному элементу,  например в моем случае это 1 и второй элемент. нулевой элемент мне не нужен.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, для полноты

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Обновил ответ. Добавил варианты, которые потребуют изменения метода.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Дополнил по примеру в вопросе

Comment: Спасибо то что надо, если миновать object то короче получается и я что то как раз упустил момент.

Comment: `v?.ToString() ?? null` какая-то бессмысленная конструкция :)

Comment: @Grundy Действительно :) Спасибо!

Comment: и теперь это можно спокойно на Cast заменить `values.Cast<string>().ToArray()`

Comment: @Grundy А там точно всегда будут только строки? Давно не лез в SqlLite если честно.

Comment: @Grundy всегда будут строки в моем случае

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch ну тогда `Cast` сработает :)

Comment: Спасибо все заработало как надо.

Comment: *//запаковали*, *//распаковали* — термин *упаковка* применим только к типам-значениям, если вы именно этот термин имели ввиду (термина "запаковка" я вообще не знаю)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Нет, это не про boxing, просто скопировал слово из вопроса. Исправил комментарии. Спасибо!